# Visual Studio 2019 MSSQL Database Login failed (permission issue)

Tags: sql-server, database

I was trying to connect to my database but i had an issue.[image]

then i tried to get my property settings but it didnt show anything :
[image]

what should i do?
i cant access my database it says login failed, login failed for me(as user).

Comment: you should check the permissions on that database. [dba.stackexchange] might be able to help

Comment: https://ibb.co/tqv21gp  i see my name on the users section, what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add user Ali to mssqllocaldb from login.
[image]

Comment: i cant display a window like you have. instead it is like this : https://ibb.co/25pY7tm   it says create login with password

Comment: For this purpose you should use SSMS.Or try write SQL: ```
USE [YourDb]
GO
CREATE USER [YourUser] FOR LOGIN [YourLogin]
GO
```

Comment: i got this. i tried to add properties at the bottom section and apply but it didnt run. but ihave my database name at top selected https://ibb.co/7k54bd1

Comment: You should check your database at the upper section for your login.

Comment: i alreay selected my database  but didnt work. please help me

Comment: Try to check **Login Properties | Status | Login | Enabled**. It must be enabled.